# Control firewalld in CentOS via Python's dbus module?

Tags: python, centos, dbus, centos7, firewalld

My goal is to automate configuring firewalls on CentOS 7 machines using Python.

The OS comes with firewalld, so that's what I'm using. I looked into it and found that it uses dbus (I've never heard of or dealt with any of this - please correct me if anything I say is incorrect.)

I found this documentation for how to control dbus processes using Python:
http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.txt

I checked and the version of Python that comes with the OS includes the `dbus` module, so it seems like a promising start.

That document suggests that I needed to learn more about what firewalld exposes via the dbus interface. So I did some more research and found this:
https://www.mankier.com/5/firewalld.dbus

The first document says I need to start out with a "well-known name". Their example for such a thing was `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager`. The second document is titled `firewalld.dbus`, so I figured that was as good a name as any to try since the document doesn't explicitly give a name anywhere else.

The first document also says I need a name for an object path. Their example is `/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager`. The second document has an object path of `/org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1`.

I put those together and tried using the first method the first document suggested, `SystemBus`'s `get_object()`:

```
>>> from dbus import SystemBus
>>> bus = SystemBus()
>>> proxy = bus.get_object('firewalld.dbus', '/org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException:
    org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:
        The name firewalld.dbus was not provided by any .service files
```

I also gave `org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1` a try as the first parameter but ended up with a similar error message.

Why are these not working? Is there some way I can discover what the proper names are? It mentions ".service files" at the end of the error message... where would such a file be located?

---

**Edit**: Found several ".service files" by using `find / -name *.service`. One of them is at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service`... seems pretty promising so I'll check it out.

**Edit 2**: It's a rather short file... only about 10 lines. One of them says `BusName=org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1`. So I'm not sure why it said the name was not provided by any .service files... unless it's not using this file for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the unit file says:

```
BusName=org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1
```

Then maybe you should try using that as your bus name:

```
>>> import dbus
>>> bus = dbus.SystemBus()
>>> p = bus.get_object('org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1', '/org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1')
>>> p.getDefaultZone()
dbus.String(u'FedoraWorkstation')
```

I figured this out based on the fact that this:

```
>>> help(bus.get_object)
```

Says that the `get_object` call looks like:

```
get_object(self, bus_name, object_path, introspect=True, follow_name_owner_changes=False, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi - as I mentioned in my original post (just before the edits) I also tried that, but it gave the same error. Is the service file not being loaded or something for some reason?

Comment: So, that just worked on my system.  The service file is used by `systemd` to start Firewalld.  Is firewalld running on your system?  What does `systemctl status firewalld` report?  Do you see a `firewalld` process running?

Comment: It was not running. I have started it now with `systemctl start firewalld.service`. Now the proxy is being created and returning answers properly. What is the best way to start the service from within Python? I was under the impression the `dbus` module would start it at the right time... or at least provide a function for starting it for me. Is my best bet going to be `subprocess.call()` or is there something I'm overlooking in the `dbus` module?

Comment: The correct thing to do is `systemctl enable firewalld` so that it is started by systemd when your system boots.

Comment: If you have a moment, could you take a look at this? I think I may have found a bug in the Python `dbus` module... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424037/dbus-to-python-takes-exactly-1-argument